# making exe file from python that uses command line arguments

Tags: python, py2exe

I want to create an exe from a python script that uses command line arguments (argv)
From what I've seen py2exe doesn't support command-line-arguments

What can I do?

EDIT: I was using a GUI2Exe tool, so I just missed the Console flag, but the accepted answer is perfectly correct

Comment: Did you try to access sys.argv in a py2exe application? What was the problem?

Comment: Don't forget to actually accept :)

Comment: I tried, I am facing this issue, please take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945860/getting-error-when-converting-a-pyscript-to-exe-using-py2exe

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

I believe the line you want to use looks like this.

I tested this with 2 files:

hello.py

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
print "Hello World!"
```

And setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

I ran these commands:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

And then in the dist folder, I ran this:

```
hello.exe foo bar
```

Result:

```
hello.exe
foo
bar
Hello World!
```

Comment: what do we need to do if we are using nltk libraries.  Do we need to copy the nltk_folder in  target machine?

Comment: I tried and facing this issue, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945860/getting-error-when-converting-a-pyscript-to-exe-using-py2exe