# Python 2.6 (Windows EXE) Keep Program Running?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I'm trying to keep my python program running but it closes right away. I have tried `raw_input()` but I get this error: `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`  I put `raw_input()` at the end. What should I use to have it running?

Comment: Do you mean prevent the console from closing? Otherwise, to keep it running use some sort of infinite loop.

Comment: @Levon Yes I thought about loop but what kind of loop will not use CPU and can safely used?

Comment: You could use a loop and put a sleep call into it to "suspend" the program periodically assuming that doesn't interfere with the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mark you can use `time.sleep()`

Comment: @Levon that will be alright, do you mind proving the code? So I can accept as an answer?

Comment: @Ashwini time.sleep() sometime will end so it will not keep it for ever alive right?...

Comment: @Mark yes it'll end sometime, but you can place it in a while loop.`while True:time.sleep(100000)`

Comment: @Ashwini adding this to end will work? No cpu 100%?

Comment: @Mark Yes, no 100% CPU load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to Python right now, but something like

```
from time import time, sleep

while True:
    #do other stuff
    sleep(5)
```

should be close. This would sleep for 5 seconds each time through the loop, see the docs for [time.sleep()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) . Adjust the time to fit your needs.

Comment: @downvoter .. why the downvote? OP seems satisfied with the answer. Downvotes w/o explanation help no one, OP, SO or me.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is compile an EXE using py2exe **specifying that it's a console app**. This is why you're getting an EOF error, there's no stdin for `raw_input()` to read from.

Create a **setup.py** like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['your_script.py'])
```

Then you can just compile it by running this in a console window:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

This will produce your_script.exe in that directory which should stay open as a console window if you have a `raw_input()` at the end of your script.

Make sure setup.py and your_script.py are in the same directory and that you have py2exe installed.

For reference, you can get [py2exe online](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage).

Incidentally, this also [allows you to use commandline arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments) in your py2exe programs.