# Running an .exe script from a VB script by passing arguments during runtime

Tags: python, vb.net, arguments

I have converted a python script to `.exe` file. I just want to run the exe file from a VB script. Now the problem is that the python script accepts arguments during run-time (e.g.: serial port number, baud rate, etc.) and I cannot do the same with the .exe file. Can someone help me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the source to the python exe convertor and if the arguments don't need to change on each execution, you could probably open the exe in a debugger like ollydbg and search for shellexecute or createprocess and then create a string in a code cave and use that for the arguments. I think that's your only option.

Another idea: Maybe make your own extractor that includes the python script, vbscript, and python interpreter. You could just use a 7zip SFX or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code of the Python script, you could change the source code and get command line arguments passed to the script from `sys.argv`, like this:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Also, the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse) module may help you if the command line interface of your script is complex.

[Documentation of sys module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

[Possibly Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments)