# Passing command line parameters to a Python script packaged as .exe with py2exe?

Tags: python, command-line, exe, py2exe, argument-passing

I have a python script that will be run as an exe (packaged using py2exe) on a machine without Python installed.  I currently have my proxy information written into the script using a proxy handler with urllib2 (see code below), but I would like to pass the user and pw as parameters written via command line, which I'm using to run the exe.  Anyone have any idea how to do this?  Any help is appreciated!

```
def get_response(url, query='', get_json=True):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(
                urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
                urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
                urllib2.ProxyHandler( 
                   {'https': 'http://user:password@myIPaddress:8080',
                    'http': 'http://user:password@myIPaddress:8080'}
                ))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    encoded = urllib.urlencode(query)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, encoded)
    if get_json:
        return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: `sys.argv` doesn't work?

Comment: haven't tried -- how/where would I use that?

Comment: See the [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#module-sys) module docs. Normally `argv[0]` is the script name and `argv[1:]` are the rest of  the command line arguments. These might be offset by 1 with py2exe -- you'll have to check it out.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken and assuming an offset for py2exe, the proxy handler should look something like this?   `{'https': 'http://' + sys.arg[0] + ':' + sys.arg[0] + 'IPaddress:8080', 'https://' + sys.arg[0] + ':' + sys.arg[0] + 'IPaddress:8080'}

Comment: Can you print, display, or otherwise output the value of `sys.argv` (note it's `argv` not `arg`) from within your py2exe'd script and see what's in it? That would tell you whether it has the information in it and what the indices of the user name and password are so you can set up the proxy with them.

Comment: this worked: {'https': 'http://' + sys.argv[0] + ':' + sys.argv[1] + '@192.168.104.103:8080',
                 'http': 'http://' + sys.argv[0] + ':' + sys.argv[1] + '@192.168.104.103:8080'}

Comment: Good, I guess, because from some things I've read, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments) answer, the `argv` argument indices don't get offset like I thought they might with py2exe -- so the ones you say worked shouldn't have.

Comment: See also [Py2exe Environment](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment) where it says "The first item in `sys.argv` is the full pathname of the executable, the rest are the command line arguments."

Comment: yup, you're right...but now i'm getting an error with indexes of 1 (for user) and 2 (for password), here's the traceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BackupService_Reworked_26_arg_unc.py", line 221, in <module>
    # ----- Change service url as necessary ----- #
  File "BackupService_Reworked_26_arg_unc.py", line 62, in login
    print response['error']
  File "BackupService_Reworked_26_arg_unc.py", line 56, in get_response

Comment: traceback cont'd:  File "urllib2.pyc", line 126, in urlopen
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 391, in open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 409, in _open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 369, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 1169, in https_open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 1136, in do_open
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authenticat
ion Required>

Comment: so in sum, it works when the user and pw are hardcoded in the script as part of the proxy url strings, but not when like this: {'https': 'http://' + sys.argv[1] + ':' + sys.argv[2] + '@192.168.104.103:8080',
'http': 'http://' + sys.argv[1] + ':' + sys.argv[2] + '@192.168.104.103:8080'} -- odd.

Comment: ...and it works with indices of 0 (for user) and 1 (for password), right? I was just pointing out that doesn't seem to match the documentation and other things I've read. Did you ever just display what was in `argv` to see what's in it like I suggested? What version of Python and py2exe are you using?

Comment: no, it doesn't work with 0 and 1 either, that was my mistake.  i just tried printing my password -- the issue is a special character in my proxy password (an ampersand) that i have to escape when typing it into the command line as a parameter.  wrapping the password in double quotes does the trick with 1 and 2 as the user and pw indices, respectively.