# Python packaging into one folder

Tags: python

I have a script that I wrote in Python. It uses some libraries such as Twython that allows me to post pictures and text to twitter. Now I am trying to make my own photo-booth that runs on Windows. I wish to run the script on the windows computer and I do not wish to install Python on the Windows machine.

I have tried to make exectuables but they do not work (I think because I have inputs that need run after the script (`python script.py Message filepath`). I thought there was a way to include everything of a normal Python install in the folder you run your script from and it will allow me run it cross platform.

Edit: My question is how can I package python up to run with out installing it preferably from a folder on the desktop.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @PaulH How to run a Python program on Windows without a full installation, I think

Comment: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage) did the job for me.

Comment: passing command line arguments with py2exe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments