# Make a Python program Icon that accepts dragged files

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I want to make a python program that shows up on the Windows desktop as an Icon and lets me drag files onto the icon to have the python script run and process the dragged files. Is there an easy way to do this?

For a simple program, I'd be happy with something that just displays a pop-up box with the names of the dragged files.

I have this working as a window that accepts drags using pyqt, but not as an icon that accepts dragged files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use py2exe to make an executable. Then that executable will receive anything that's dropped into it as an argument. See this answer for more information: [making exe file from python that uses command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments)