# python command line options to a compiled python file (py2exe)

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, py2exe, cpython

I, like many python programmers find the command line arguments for python described [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html) very useful. specifically "-i" which keeps the python interpreter running after a program finishes for a stack trace.  How can I use these with an exe file compiled with py2exe?  Not to be confused with regular argument parsing in an exe file. If you came looking for that, find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497370/making-exe-file-from-python-that-uses-command-line-arguments).
My first thought was to try:

```
pyprogram.exe -i -foo -bar
```

but that didn't work.
it should be noted that

```
pyprogram.exe -foo -bar
```

does in fact work for me.
what I am looking for is the .exe equivalent of

```
python -i pyprogram.py foo bar
```

Failing to find an implementation that works for all of the python command line options, what could I do just to make the "-i" argument work?  it is the most important to have as an option in my executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find anything on the [py2exe wiki](http://www.py2exe.org/) about passing arguments like [`-i`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) (to enter interactive mode after execution).

---

One might be able to discover information about the argument handling in the [py2exe source files](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/py2exe/).
*Update:* It indeed looks like py2exe does not handle any command line options like the normal interpreter does, instead it just [passes](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/py2exe-3/source/start.c#l410) them to the script. But it does [handle](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/py2exe-3/source/start.c#l159) the respective environment variable, which can be used as shown below.

---

However, as a workaround, you could try to [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) the [`PYTHONINSPECT` Environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONINSPECT):

> If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to specifying the -i option.

E.g. run `set PYTHONINSPECT=TRUE` before running the program.

But, probably even better, this can be done from within the Python script:

> This variable can also be modified by Python code using os.environ to force inspect mode on program termination.

Here's a little test script for [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) (also [os.putenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.putenv)):

```
import os
one = os.environ
os.putenv("PYTHONINSPECT", "TRUE")
two = os.environ

os.environ["PYTHONINSPECT"] = "TRUE"
three = os.environ
print(one)
print(two)
print(three)
print( set(one.items()) ^ set(two.items()) )
print( set(one.items()) ^ set(three.items()) )
```

The behaviour is a little weird: there does not seem to be a difference, and it seems to only last until you exit the interactive mode:

```
G:\>py test.py > test.txt
>>> exit()

G:\>set PYTHONINSPECT
Environment variable PYTHONINSPECT not defined
```

The contents of `test.txt` are:

```
environ({'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', ... 'PYTHONINSPECT': 'TRUE'})
environ({'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', ... 'PYTHONINSPECT': 'TRUE'})
environ({'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', ... 'PYTHONINSPECT': 'TRUE'})
set()
set()
```

But it seems to work either way (double check the documentation for yourself to ensure you are not corrupting your environment variables), so you could even implement an `-i` argument for yourself like:

```
import sys, os
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '-i':
    os.putenv("PYTHONINSPECT", "TRUE")
    #os.environ["PYTHONINSPECT"] = "TRUE"
    print("interactive")
else:
    print("normal")
```

which runs as follows

```
G:\>py test.py
normal

G:\>py test.py -i
interactive
>>> quit()

G:\>set PYTHONINSPECT
Environment variable PYTHONINSPECT not defined
```

---

Trying with py2exe and [Python 3.4.3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/) (newer versions are apparently not supported and [you get an IndexError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe)):

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['test.py'])
```

Get py2exe

```
G:\>c:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install py2exe
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 10.0.0b2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting py2exe
  Using cached py2exe-0.9.2.2-py33.py34-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: py2exe

Successfully installed py2exe-0.9.2.2
```

Run py2exe

```
G:\>c:\Python34\python.exe setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

  3 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
Building 'dist\test.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy c:\Python34\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
```

Test

```
G:\>dist\test.exe
normal

G:\>dist\test.exe -i
interactive
>>> sys.exit()
```

Does not seem to have changed the environment variables permanently:

```
G:\>set PYTHONINSPECT
Environment variable PYTHONINSPECT not defined
```

---

Also works with [single exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113014/1619432):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    console = [{'script': "test.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```